# Any way to improve framerate of jQuery animations?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm working on a website that uses a lot of javascript animations to display content and I noticed jQuery does a poor job when it comes to making animations appear smooth?

How can I overcome this apparent limitation of jQuery?

Comment: Maybe a little more detail about your scenario can help. Or do you find this limitation of JQuery in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's animations, unlike, say, css animations, are not hardware-accelerated and this is the reason why they are not as smooth. Also jQuery isn't meant for implementations that rely heavily on animations and you should take a look at other solutions:

[Velocity](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) is an animation engine that integrated seamlessly with jQuery and outperforms jQuery at all levels of stress.

Also, for more advanced and hardcore stuff definitely take a look at [Greensock](http://greensock.com/).